# Unknown numbers in quickContactBadge

Tags: android, android-intent

This question is possible duplicate of [Android QuickContact Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486373/android-quickcontact-badge)

I am able to show my app icon in the quickContactBadge that is shown on a stored contact with a name by writting this in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/name" />
</intent-filter>
```

This is of course not working for not stored (unknown) numbers. I was searching in the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE and this should be sufficient:

```
<intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/calls" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, it does display nothing... I searched on the web and somme google apps are not using it anymore (sorry, can't find the diff anymore) but I could not find any equivalent.

Sufficient for me would to resolve this for version Android 4.+

Thank you for any tips.